# Eloquent relationship between array items and other tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having trouble understanding what I need to make this relationship work.

I have a form for product updates with 3 fields. *Update ID*, *Description*, and *Areas Affected*.

The *Areas Affected* is a group of check boxes for each work area in our building. When its submitted the selected areas are stored as an array in my table. I need to create a relationship between these areas and all of the people in them so that when I'm displaying the list of product updates I can also list all of the people affected by this update.

At this point I have 3 tables.

1. update_info - id, description, affected_areas
2. update_people - id, name, area_id
3. update_areas - id, area

I don't understand how to go about making the array of *affected areas* relate to the update_areas and then each area relate to the personnel with that area id. Is my approach way off?

`public function create(Request $request)

```
{


    $update = new Update;

    $update->id = $request->number;

    $update->description = $request->description;

    $update->areas()->sync($request->input('area'));

    $update->save();

    return view('updates.index');

}`
```

Doing this I get a fatal error.

*Fatal error: Call to a member function sync() on null*

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way, you need a pivot table probably called something like `update_info_areas` but it's your choice.  This of this pivot table as just something to help expand out those arrays in your table so that the database can use them to join on additional tables.  If your `update_info` of id 1 has 10 areas, in your pivot table, that would be 10 records where `update_info_id` is 1 for each record and `area_id` would be the `id` of each `area` which relates to that `update_info`.

This table would have an `update_info_id` column which would relate to your `update_info.id` column and an `area_id` column which would relate to your `update_areas.id` column.

That would get you a `belongsToMany` relationship between `update_info` and `update_areas`.

To use this to add records, it would be quite simple.

As an example, let's say you are trying to set areas of id 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6 to the `update_info` with id of 1.

```
$updateInfo = UpdateInfo::find(1);
$updateInfo->areas()->sync([1,3,4,5,6]);
```

This would first remove all of the areas associated with that updated info and re-add the selected areas.

If you wanted to just attach or detach a certain area without removing everything already existing for that area... it would be just as simple.  Let's say you now want to remove areas 1 and 3 from that `update_info`, but then also attach area 2.

```
$updateInfo = UpdateInfo::find(1);
$updateInfo->areas()->detach([1,3]);
$updateInfo->areas()->attach([2]);
```

Comment: So when the form is submitted would I loop through the array of areas in my controller to make a new entry for each area in update_info_areas? Is there a better way to handle the  array passed to the controller from the form?

Comment: That is the general idea however Laravel provides some methods when using belongsToMany that do that to make it a lot easier.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Alright I think I've got the relationships figured out but when the form passes the array to my controller the data looks something like: 
`"area" => array:4 [▼
        0 => "CPT"
        1 => "ENGINEERING TECH"
        2 => "LAYOUT"
        3 => "PRODUCTION MANAGER"
      ]`
Do I need to query the my update areas table to get the _id_ for each of these to then use the sync function?

Comment: That would work yes.  However when I build my forms, I set the values of the check boxes to the id's found within the database so I don't have to re-query for them later.

Comment: `public function create(Request $request)

    {

        
        $update = new Update;

        $update->id = $request->number;

        $update->description = $request->description;

        $update->areas()->sync($request->input('area'));

        $update->save();

        return view('updates.index');

    }`

Doing this I get a fatal error.

_Fatal error: Call to a member function sync() on null_

Comment: That means you don't have an `areas` method on your `Update` model.  Replace `area` with whatever you named your method to setup that `belongsToMany` relationship.